# Cómo programo una variable que acumule String?

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy programando un diccionario, para lo que necesito crear un historial de todas las palabras buscadas.
No puedo crear en Android Studio una variable String que me permita **Acumular** las palabras que se buscaron. Por el contrario lo único que logro es que la ultima búsqueda reemplace a la anterior en vez de concatenarse.

Acá dejo el código que me permite enviar en un intent la última palabra buscada como "dato".

```
        else if(id == R.id.historial){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, HistorialGlosario.class);
        i.putExtra("dato", tv2.getText().toString());
        startActivity(i);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Historial", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
```

Acá en la otra activity dejo el código que me permite recibir el "dato", pero **no sé cómo acumularlo en la variable String** para después mostrarlo en el TextView.

```
       tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_texthistorial);
               String dato = getIntent().getStringExtra("dato");
               tv1.setText(dato);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero obtienes el texto actual de `tv1` y luego le concatenas el nuevo valor:

```
tv1.setText(tv1.getText().toString() + " " +dato);
```

**Actualización:**

En la segunda activity, crea una variable estática de tipo String y úsala como contenedor:

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompactActivity{
   private static String contenedor = "";

  // resto de código
   tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_texthistorial);
   String dato = getIntent().getStringExtra("dato");
   contenedor += " " + dato;
   tv1.setText(contenedor); 


}
```

Comment: No funciona, me muestra solo la última búsqueda.

Comment: Agregué una actualización.

Comment: @carrlos Ahora sí, mi problema era que no sabía que tenia que declarar la variante de acumulacíon como **private state String**, ahora funciona perfecto.

Answer (score 0):

Yo usaría un ArrayList:

```
List<String> historial = new ArrayList();
```

Agregas palabras a la lista así:

```
historial.add("Palabra a");
historial.add("Palabra b");
historial.add("Palabra c");
historial.add("Palabra n");
```

Y recorres la lista así:

```
for(String palabra : historial) {
    Log.d("TAG", palabra);
}
```

O si quieres obtener el primer elemento:

```
historial.get(0);
```

O si quieres obtener el último elemento:

```
historial.get(historial.size() - 1);
```